# GameCenter doesn't use sandbox mode

Tags: sandbox, game-center

my app doesn't use GameCenter in sandbox mode on my iPhone. Usually (on my old and new iPad) the sandbox mode is enabled after I started a development which was installed through Xcode with dev-profiles. It disables GC when you launch an app which was installed through GameCenter. 
I've already tried several things: Logging out and in in the GC app and int the settings app, restoring the iPhone, deleting the app. I don't know what to do next and need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log OUT in the GC app. Make sure your app is registered in itunesconnect.apple.com even though you're not ready to submit it yet. Then make sure game center is enabled for it in itunesconnect. Then launch the app and log into GC from within the app. You should then be in sandbox mode.